# Atribuição múltipla em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Como atribuir vários valores a um atributo de uma tabela no MySQL? Por exemplo uma tabela  onde um cliente possa ter vários telefones, e na atribuição possa ser passado os vários telefones do cliente de uma vez.

Comment: Se o numero de telefones for variável podes colocar numa string com um separador tipo `|`? Se pode variar entre 1 e 3 podes ter 3 colunas e inserir vazio caso não haja... que achas dessa ideia?

Comment: Votei pra fechar como não clara porque a pergunta pede para colocar vários valores em um atributo da tabela. A resposta aceita sugere criar uma outra tabela para fazer isto, então a pergunta era outra.

Comment: Coloquei como aceita, por que não sabia, que não era possível fazer essas atribuições compostas de uma vez só,  agora tirou minha duvida em relação a isso, e de como fazer de uma outra forma, que é criando uma nova tabela.

Comment: Peço desculpa também, o erro também foi meu em ter respondido a outra coisa senão aquilo, sugeri uma coisa melhor face ao exemplo clientes/telefones. Realmente tem razão @bigown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Face ao problema clientes/telefones a melhor maneira é criar uma tabela com `telefones` visto que é uma relação de muitos para um (`1:N`) um cliente para muitos telefones.

Ou seja:

`clientes`

**id | nome | email|**

1 | Miguel | miguel@miguel.com

2 | Bruno | bruno@bruno.com

3| Maria | maria@maria.com

`telefones`

**id | id_cliente | telefone**

1 | 1 | 32432342

2 | 2 | 3244234

3| 2 | 4324234

4| 1 | 5435435

5| 1 | 4325423

6| 3 | 3243324

Assim você pode associar o cliente ao telefone/telefones que ele tem pelo `id_cliente`, por ex: o Miguel tem os telefones 32432342, 5435435, 4325423, vemos isso pois o `id_cliente` na tabela dos telefones é o `1` que é o `id` do Miguel na tabela `clientes`.

EX:
O comando `SQL` para selecionar os `telefones` do Miguel é:

```
SELECT telefones.* FROM telefones JOIN clientes ON telefones.id_cliente = clientes.id WHERE clientes.id = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

O MySQL não tem nada próprio que faça isto. Tem banco de dados que possuí um tipo *array* que permite fazer isto de forma relativamente simples (nem é tão simples assim).

O normal é criar várias colunas e deixar nulo quando não tem os dados extras. Em banco de dados que trabalha com linhas de tamanho variável, isto não chega ser um grande problema na maioria dos casos.

A solução mais comum é fazer normalização e criar uma tabela para armazenar estes dados que podem ser múltiplos. Claro que isto tem lá sua complexidade e piora a performance, o que pode ou não ser um problema para sua aplicação. Veja como fazer na resposta do Miguel (ainda que isto não seja o que foi perguntado).

Um truque pode ser aplicado e usar uma coluna `VARCHAR` para guardar estes dados com separadores. Não é tão simples fazer isto e tem vários complicadores pra fazer consultas. Só recomendo se for muito necessário, o desenvolvedor for bem experiente para fazer isto e entender o todo antes de se aventurar. Mas não deixa de ser uma solução. Outros tipos podem ser usados também se forem mais adequados, por exemplo [JSON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) que já possui algumas facilidades no banco de dados para lidar com isto (e foi melhorando com o tempo).